If I install the windows service program in c# on another computer, I encounter such an error
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility Version 4.8.9032.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

I get this error:

Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\user\Desktop\AptekaBeta\AptekaBeta.exe' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515).

I installed it on another computer in this way through the .bat file adminstrator
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
InstallUtil.exe  C:\Users\user\Desktop\AptekaBeta\AptekaBeta.exe

However, this is how it works on my computer.
Service should be installed in Windows

Check if all the dependencies required by AptekaBeta.exe are present on the target location.

The PATH statement looks suspicious. Path segments must be separated by semicolon rather in than spaces.

As @Chethan-M already suggested, probably a dependency is missing. To figure out which one, use the Fusion Log Viewer (fuslogvw.exe) as described here. It can tell you exactly which dependencies it tries to load, where it tries to find them and if it succeeded or not.
